# NSMutableArray not updating

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

im kinda new to iOS, I'm having a hard time with my array, I'm using `NSMutableArray`,I have put my array in the `AppDelegate`, 
At first load of the app in my `viewController` the array has no object in it yet, I have a setting that put my integers in the array, 
but after saving the array was not loaded, but when exited then reOpen, it will load, 
Could please someone explain how can I solve and why is it like this?
Im using it `tableview`.

in `app delegate`:

```
self.integers = [NSMutableArray array];  
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
{ .....
  }
```

loading:

```
integers = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).integers;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

Somewhere in your code you have a loop that loads your integers and puts them into your array, right?
You need to put that loop in a method and call it again whenever you want to reset the `UITableVIew` contents back to its original contents.
Then you need to update the array in your `AppDelegate` and your `viewController`, so depending which class that method is in, you'll need to copy the integers to the other class using

```
integers = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).integers;
```

or

```
// your array then update
self.integerss = [NSMutableArray array];  

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
    { .....
      }

((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).integers = self.integers;
```

Use the same code you used for the array originally to put all the integers back, then call `reloadData` on the `tableview`.
That will solve your problem.

Comment: This will indeed solve your problem but I would also recommend rearranging your design - I can see no good reason why the application delegate should have anything to do with the app data layer and hold an array of integers.

Comment: I mean that the AppDelegate class is not meant for whatever you're using it for. Developers tend to make this mistake often because it is the first code that runs. I would recommend moving this data entity to a class that manages data.